# Explanation behind value returned by int x=printf

Tags: c, printf

I was randomly experimenting with code and tried to assign `printf` to an integer variable, using different compilers. Different values were returned. What is the explanation for that?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int x;
  x = printf;
  printf ("%d", x);
  return 0;
}
```

Value returned on my compiler is `4195360`.

Comment: This is really an interesting question from a new C programmer.  And it's one that's really hard for a new C programmer to find the answer because you need to know what words to search for before you can find the answer.  And if you knew those words you'd already know what's going on here.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the warnings from your compiler. (If your compiler doesn't show a warning for this code, look up how to configure it to show useful warnings.)

```
a.c:5:5: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int'
      from 'int (const char *, ...)' [-Wint-conversion]
  x = printf;
    ^ ~~~~~~
1 warning generated.
```

`printf` is a function. Every function can be used as a pointer to that function. A pointer to a function is a way to refer to the function that can be placed into a variable. Typically, it's the address of the code of the function in memory.

It's possible to assign a pointer to an integer. The resulting value depends on your system. The integer is typically the address of the code of the function in memory.

There's nothing useful you can do with this value except in some very particular circumstances (such as crafting binary exploits, or managing dynamic code loading). Anything you can do with the value would be very specific to a particular hardware and software environment.